block-structure matrix
I am doing some code for my note and I encountered some block-structure matrices, so I googled how to make them in latex. From the nicematrix user manual I copied the code, and it works fine. Here is the photo and code:

$\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \hline
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots& \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}$

However, as you can see, there is a problem with the horizontal line and the partial derivatives. How can I fix it? I want some gaps between the horizontal line and fractions. I tried to fix it, but it didn't work. Please have a look at it.

As always on here, please extend your sniplet to a full but minimal example others can copy and work with as is. BTW: Why such a large matrix in the running text? (inside $...$)

I've taken the liberty of editing the title and first sentence of your query, as the matrix you're looking to typeset isn't actually block-diagonal, but just "block-y".

Try to use midrule of booktabs pqackage::
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \midrule
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots& \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}


Edit:
with considering @Mico comment (thank you for it!), instead of \midrule in this special case can be used \toprule[\lightrulewidth] which not add vertical space above rule:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \toprule[\lightrulewidth]
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots& \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}


Or use arraystretch:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.2}
\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \hline
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots& \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}



+1. A downside of \midrule is that it inserts whitespace both above and below the rule, even though no extra whitespace is needed above the rule. You could suggest executing \toprule[\lightrulewidth], which inserts whiteapace below the rule only.

@Mico, good idea. I need to remember it ... Thank you very much!

Thanks. The first one works fine.

I suggest you (a) increase \arraystretch and (b) insert a (typographic) strut -- say, ^{\mathstrut} -- in the numerator portion of one of the \frac expressions in the final row. These adjustments may be performed both with a bNiceArray environment and a standard-LaTeX array environment.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25} % default: 1.0
\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} 
& & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ 
\hline
\dfrac{\partial f^{\mathstrut}}{\partial x_1} & 
\cdots & 
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & 
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}
\qquad
\left[ \begin{array}{@{} ccc|c @{}}
&     & & 0      \\
& I_n & & \vdots \\
&     & & 0      \\ 
\hline
\dfrac{\partial f^{\mathstrut}}{\partial x_1} & 
\cdots & 
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & 
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{array}\right]
\]

\end{document}


Add a strut, in this case \smash[b]{\vphantom{\Bigg|}}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \hline
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} &
  \cdots &
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} &
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
  \smash[b]{\vphantom{\Bigg|}}
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}



I suggest using the key cell-space-top-limit (the name is inspired by the well-kown package cellspace).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin,cell-space-top-limit=2pt]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \hline
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots& \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}


It's also possible to apply that parameter to only one row by using the key of the command \RowStyle with the same name (cell-space-top-limit).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{cw{c}{1cm}c|c}[margin]
\Block{3-3}{I_n} & & & 0 \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & 0 \\ \hline
\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=2pt]{}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots& \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}

In the present case, the output is the same, of course...
